# Using OpenLayers to display image only?

Tags: openlayers-2, imagery

I have a high resolution image, which I've broken down into tiles and named the tiles according to x,y co-ordinates and zoom levels. The image is not projected in any geospatial/gis (WGS84 ellipsoid, spherical mercator) ellipsoid.

If it is possible to use OpenLayers (version 2.x) to display the image in the browser, then how should I go about doing that?

Note that I also want to be able to overlay the image with other data, and OL allows me to do this easily on a map but not entirely sure if I can do this with an image.

Comment: for Openlayers 3, I could recommend the zoomify Projection: http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/zoomify.html

Comment: The entire application, which is fairly large, is built in OL 2. Unless porting to OL 3 is incredibly simple, it is hard for me to justify using it just for this purpose. However, there must be a way to do this in OL 2, I think.

Comment: I am afraid it is not that simple to switch to OL3. But maybe there's a solution for you when you use the GDAL command "gdal2tiles" (http://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html). It should create tiles of your original image and will provide you also with an OpenLayers html file.

Comment: That looks very interesting. I will try that today and update you about my results. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can show tile image in browser by following code:

```
var Layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS("map", "", {'type':'png', 'getURL':get_my_url,isBaseLayer:true});
```

and get_my_url function is:

```
function get_my_url(bounds) {

var res = this.map.getResolution();
if (url instanceof Array) {
    url = this.selectUrl(path, url);
}
var x = Math.round((bounds.left - this.maxExtent.left) / (res * this.tileSize.w));
var y = Math.round((this.maxExtent.top - bounds.top) / (res * this.tileSize.h));

var z = this.map.getZoom();
var path = z + "_" + x + "_" + y + "." + this.type;
var url = this.url;

return url + path;
```

}

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem. However, now I have another problem that is related to this one. Please take a look here:
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171267/transforming-openlayers-geometry